# wordprees multi-site in user panel

Tags: wordpress

I want to add a new custom filter in WordPress network admin

restrict_manage_users for network admin in the user panel[image]

I want a custom filter option not a custom column, i just want to add one filter dropdown with roles

Answer (score 1):

You will need to hook on the `restrict_manage_posts` filters to add your filter (dropdown) and to `parse_query` to alter the query according to the filter selection.

For example, If you want to add a filter to display a list of years for the user to select, add the following code in your ***functions.php*** file:

```php
if (is_admin()){
   //this hook will create a new filter on the admin area for the specified post type
   add_action( 'restrict_manage_posts', function(){
        global $wpdb, $table_prefix;

        $post_type = (isset($_GET['post_type'])) ? quote_smart($_GET['post_type'], true) : 'post';
 
        //only add filter to post type you want
        if ($post_type == 'YOUR_POST_TYPE_HERE'){
            //query database to get a list of years for the specific post type:
            $values = array();
            $query_years = $wpdb->get_results("SELECT year(post_date) as year from ".$table_prefix."posts
                    where post_type='".$post_type."'
                    group by year(post_date)
                    order by post_date");
            foreach ($query_years as &$data){
                $values[$data->year] = $data->year;
            }

            //give a unique name in the select field
            ?><select name="admin_filter_year">
<option value="">All years</option>

                <?php 
                $current_v = isset($_GET['admin_filter_year'])? $_GET['admin_filter_year'] : '';
                foreach ($values as $label => $value) {
                    printf(
                        '<option value="%s"%s>%s</option>',
                        $value,
                        $value == $current_v? ' selected="selected"':'',
                        $label
                    );
                }
                ?>
            </select>
            <?php
        }
    });

    //this hook will alter the main query according to the user's selection of the custom filter we created above:
    add_filter( 'parse_query', function($query){
        global $pagenow;
        $post_type = (isset($_GET['post_type'])) ? quote_smart($_GET['post_type'], true) : 'post';

        if ($post_type == 'YOUR_POST_TYPE_HERE' && $pagenow=='edit.php' && isset($_GET['admin_filter_year']) && !empty($_GET['admin_filter_year'])) {
            $query->query_vars['year'] = $_GET['admin_filter_year'];
        }
    });
}
```

Using this technique you can actually add any filter you want.

I hope this will solve your problem.

Answer (score 0):

```
add_filter( 'wpmu_users_columns', 'my_awesome_new_column' );

add_action( 'manage_users_custom_column', 'my_awesome_column_data', 10, 3 );

// Creates a new column in the network users table and puts it before a chosen column
function my_awesome_new_column( $columns ) {
    return my_awesome_add_element_to_array( $columns, 'my-awesome-column', 'Awesome', 'registered' );
}

// Adds data to our new column
function my_awesome_column_data( $value, $column_name, $user_id ) {

    // If this our column, we return our data
    if ( 'my-awesome-column' == $column_name ) {
        return 'Awesome user ID ' . intval( $user_id );
    }

    // If this is not any of our custom columns we just return the normal data
    return $value;
}

// Adds a new element in an array on the exact place we want (if possible).
function my_awesome_add_element_to_array( $original_array, $add_element_key, $add_element_value, $add_before_key ) {

    // This variable shows if we were able to add the element where we wanted
    $added = 0;

    // This will be the new array, it will include our element placed where we want
    $new_array = array();

    // We go through all the current elements and we add our new element on the place we want
    foreach( $original_array as $key => $value ) {

        // We put the element before the key we want
        if ( $key == $add_before_key ) {
            $new_array[ $add_element_key ] = $add_element_value;

            // We were able to add the element where we wanted so no need to add it again later
            $added = 1;
        }

        // All the normal elements remain and are added to the new array we made
        $new_array[ $key ] = $value;
    }

    // If we failed to add the element earlier (because the key we tried to add it in front of is gone) we add it now to the end
    if ( 0 == $added ) {
        $new_array[ $add_element_key ] = $add_element_value;
    }

    // We return the new array we made
    return $new_array;
}
```

Here is an example : https://wordpress.stackexchange.com/questions/299801/custom-column-under-all-users-multisite-network-admin

Comment: I want a custom filter option not a custom column, i just want to add one filter dropdown with roles